# Unable to remap Win+2 key combination in 19.10

Tags: 19.10, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 in VirtualBox.
I wanted to remap the key combination Win+2. 
The keyboard configuration applet shows it as unused, but when I press it, it opened Thunderbird.

After unsuccessfully trying to unmap this key combination, I uninstalled Thunderbird. Now Win+2 opens Files app, pointing at my home folder. 
How can I unmap this key combination?

Comment: try to install `dconf-editor` and then search for the key combinations in this image.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu0RO.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at keyboard assignments defined by the Ubuntu Dock. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> opens, or switches to, the application on the first, second, third position of the dock.

To disable this functionality of the Ubuntu Dock, and release these hotkeys for other uses, execute the following command in a terminal or in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```